# Ajax asynchronous issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

Im building a mobile app with backbone.js. It allows users to choose football players on a team. I want the app to remember what players have been choosen if the users stop half way through. Im doing this with local storage. So say the user returns to the "choose players" page after exiting prematurely, having already choosen 2 players. I generate a html string for this page with:

html_string = template();

This is a series of divs and nested divs. I then get the saved_selection from local storage:

```
saved_selection = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('match_selection'));
console.log(saved_selected);
```

The output is:

```
Object {236: "Forward_2", 243: "Forward_1"}
```

The key is the player id and the value is their position. Next, I loop through each object key-value pair and replace matched divs (i dont provide that in this example). So the full render function is:

```
    render: function (forArr) {
        saved_selection = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('match_selection'));

        html_string = template({forArr:forArr, saved_selection:saved_selection});

        console.log(saved_selection);

        if(UsefulFuncs.getObjSize(saved_selection)>0){
                for(var index in saved_selection) {  
                    var player = new models.Player({id: index});
                    player.fetch({success:function(model) {
                console.log('in success');  
            //do some matching and div replacement
                            html_string = "The new html string";
                       }});

                }
        }
        this.$el.html(html_string);
        return this;
    },
```

I can see in the output that it goes into the success twice, but the returned html is still the original template, and not "The new html string"....I think this may be something to do with asynchronous calls....

Comment: `this.$el.html(html_string);` is happening before `html_string = "The new html string";`.

Comment: how do i ensure everything in "success" is executed first?

Comment: *"how do i ensure everything in "success" is executed first?"* You don't. Just move everything that you need to run after success is executed inside the success callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
render: function (forArr) {
    saved_selection = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('match_selection'));

    html_string = template({forArr:forArr, saved_selection:saved_selection});

    console.log(saved_selection);

    if(UsefulFuncs.getObjSize(saved_selection)>0){
            for(var index in saved_selection) {  
                var player = new models.Player({id: index});
                player.fetch({
                    success: function(model) {
                        console.log('in success');  
                        //do some matching and div replacement
                        html_string = "The new html string";
                        this.$el.html(html_string);
                    }});
            }
    }
    else {
        this.$el.html(html_string);
    }
    return this;
},
```

You need to do the html replacement within the callback, otherwise the content will get replaced before the value of `html_string` changes.